# How to get TimeZone of EC2 instance via CLI or Boto3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, timezone

How to get TimeZone of EC2 instance via CLI or Boto3

I tried using `aws ec2 get-console-output` in CLI. But getting the Time Zone of Windows instance only.

```
call aws ec2 get-console-output --instance-id
```

How to get the TimeZone of the Linux instance? Also what if an user have changed the TimeZone of an instance and has not restarted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon EC2 provisions the virtual infrastructure for the instance, but has **no access to what is running "inside" the instance**. To obtain information from the operating system, there needs to be some software running on the virtual computer itself.

This means you will need to install some software that can provide this information. A suitable means of doing this would be to use the [AWS Systems Manager Run Command](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/systems-manager/latest/userguide/execute-remote-commands.html), which can run remote commands. First, you must install the AWS Systems Manager Agent. Then, you can trigger commands to run on one or multiple instances.